# How to draw a circle's shading in iText5

Tags: java, itext

I would like to draw a ring pie chart with its shading which color is start from `BaseColor.WHITE` to `BaseColor.GREEN`.

I used the `pdfShading` function. It fails when the X and Y axis' coordinate value are the same.

The pie chart isn't generated.

```
PdfShadingPattern pattern;
PdfShading axial;
axial = PdfShading.simpleAxial(canvas.getPdfWriter(), 0, 76, 0, 76,BaseColor.WHITE, BaseColor.GREEN);       
pattern = new PdfShadingPattern(axial);
canvas.setShadingFill(pattern);

canvas.setShadingStroke(pattern);
canvas.fill();
```

Comment: how to define each parameter? I want to ring circle, such as two circles with the same center point but different radius.

Answer (score 0):

To draw a circle you need to use `simpleRadial` instead of `simpleAxial`. Like:

```
axial = PdfShading.simpleRadial(canvas.getPdfWriter(), 0, 76, 5, 0, 76, 5,BaseColor.WHITE, BaseColor.GREEN);
```

Comment: how to define each parameter? I want to ring circle, such as two circles with the same center point but different radius.

Comment: @Ludy.li by params: `x0, y0, r0, x1, y1, r1`. To manage radius change `r0` and `r1` params. In the example - 5.

Comment: there are two circles, I want to draw a ring pie circle which has two radius